# Japanese character

Tags: character-encoding

I'm making a website, all the page will be in English except I need few pages with Japanese tekst (Japanese character).
Is it possible? How can I do it?

Francois

Comment: Have you tried adding this copy already and it isn't working? What isn't working? What have you tried?

Comment: I did not, I have no idea how to do it

Comment: First thing to try is just adding Japanese copy into a text area and test the content display in a template... Does it display as needed?

Comment: I did copy some japanse tekst and the result is goed. If I take a look in the source I see that the Japanese text get this form:&#22922;&#23072;&#12373;&#12428;&#12390;&#12363;&#12425;&#12289;&#65304;&#36913;&#30446;&#65374;&#65297;&#65298;&#36913;&#30446;&#12398;&#38291;

Comment: Okay... So are you all sorted then? Sounds like it's working on the front-end.